# Warning [parser.cc:536] XML Attribute[***] in element[***] not defined in SDF, ignoring

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I try to set inertial parameters of the imported object in sdf. It seems it [works](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17057/problem-with-reading-inertia-values-from-sdf-in-gazebo/) for other people, however for me it results in warnings. Neither mass, nor moments of inertia, nor CoM are set in Gazebo. I use ROS Kinetic and Gazebo 7.0.0 under Ubuntu 16.04.
What could be a problem here?

**sdf file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.6">
  <model name="kitchen_spatula">
    <static>false</static>
    <link name="link">
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      <inertial>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.13606 0.00000 0.02002"/>
    <mass value="0.14867"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.00016"
             ixy="0.00000"
             ixz="0.00030"
             iyy="0.00113"
             iyz="0.00000"
             izz="0.00106"/>
      </inertial>
      <visual name="visual">
    <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    <geometry>
      <mesh>
        <uri>model://kitchen_spatula/low_poly_paddle.STL</uri>
        <!-- Whatever unit you use in stl, it will be treated as meters by Gazebo:
        http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8294/mesh-scale-huge-for-stl-file/ -->
        <scale>0.001 0.001 0.001</scale>
      </mesh>
    </geometry>
    <material>
      <script>
        <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
        <name>Gazebo/Orange</name>
      </script>
    </material>
      </visual>
      <collision name="collision">
    <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    <geometry>
      <mesh>
        <uri>model://kitchen_spatula/low_poly_paddle.STL</uri>
        <scale>0.001 0.001 0.001</scale>
      </mesh>
    </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

**output:**

```
[INFO] [1543493481.499131, 0.000000]: Loading model XML from ros parameter
[INFO] [1543493481.500796, 0.000000]: Waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
Warning [parser.cc:778] XML Element[origin], child of element[inertial] not defined in SDF. Ignoring[origin]. You may have an incorrect SDF file, or an sdformat version that doesn't support this element.
Warning [parser.cc:536] XML Attribute[value] in element[mass] not defined in SDF, ignoring.
Warning [parser.cc:536] XML Attribute[ixx] in element[inertia] not defined in SDF, ignoring.
Warning [parser.cc:536] XML Attribute[ixy] in element[inertia] not defined in SDF, ignoring.
Warning [parser.cc:536] XML Attribute[ixz] in element[inertia] not defined in SDF, ignoring.
Warning [parser.cc:536] XML Attribute[iyy] in element[inertia] not defined in SDF, ignoring.
Warning [parser.cc:536] XML Attribute[iyz] in element[inertia] not defined in SDF, ignoring.
Warning [parser.cc:536] XML Attribute[izz] in element[inertia] not defined in SDF, ignoring.
[ INFO] [1543493482.285987182, 0.021000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1543493482.315061083, 0.049000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21230/warning-%5Bparser.cc:536%5D-xml-attribute%5B***%5D-in-element%5B***%5D-not-defined-in-sdf,-ignoring./) by [ivan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7391/ivan/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-11-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It looks like you are using [URDF](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf) syntax inside [SDF](http://sdformat.org/). You have:

```
<inertial>
<origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.13606 0.00000 0.02002"/>
<mass value="0.14867"/>
<inertia ixx="0.00016"
          ixy="0.00000"
          ixz="0.00030"
          iyy="0.00113"
          iyz="0.00000"
          izz="0.00106"/>
</inertial>
```

Instead, it should be:

```
<inertial>
  <pose>0.13606 0.00000 0.02002 0 0 0</pose>
  <inertia>
    <ixx>0.00016</ixx>
    <ixy>0</ixy>
    <ixz>0.00030</ixz>
    <iyy>0.00113</iyy>
    <iyz>0</iyz>
    <izz>0.00106</izz>
  </inertia>
  <mass>0.14867</mass>
</inertial>
```

You can find out more about the SDF syntax [here](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.6&elem=link)

---

Originally posted by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) with karma: 704 on 2018-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ivan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7391/ivan/) on 2018-11-29**:
Thanks for help! I will check it next week and get back with result.

**Comment by [ivan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7391/ivan/) on 2018-12-10**:
Thanks again, it works now. I could not realize that these syntaxs are incompatible.